# add full path to a field after find operation in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am having one question please help me i am using find function and getting the data below this format .i want to add a full path to my image field after  find

```
[Category] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Chicken
                    [description] => Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur
                    [image] => 20140124121626.jpg
                    [restaurant_id] => 1
                )
        )
```

can i extendt this like 'http://website.com/files/restaurants/thumb/20140124120912.jpg'

Thanks

Comment: you can make use of `afterFind` to modify your array after a find operation

Comment: If you want to display image in view file, I will suggest you to use HtmlHelper to do your work.

Comment: is there any way like while finding concatenate string or set::extract  something i am not sure ..

Comment: Rikesh no i will encode this data for my web services so no issue of form helper

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->Category->virtualFields['new_image'] = 'CONCAT(" SITE URL HERE",Category.image)';
$data = $this->Category->find('first');
pr($data);
```

hope its will help you :)

Comment: @sismaster if its useful for you , then you can vote my answer :)

Comment: Sorry Mate I don't have at least reputation but i will do soon once i will get ..